# How to edit particular object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a UI from my JSON data in react, where I am creating tab and nested some elements in each tab which is working fine.

I have a delete button for each tab so when I click delete it is removing that particulate tab.

I am also nesting elements inside my tabs, so now I am trying to delete those elements on click of the corresponding button, but I am getting an error.

To create new tab I am doing this:

```js
      const addNewTab = () => {
        const name = window.prompt("Enter Name");
        if (name) {
          setData((data) => [...data, new Data(id, name)]);
        }
      };
```

And to create new elements inside that tab:

```js
      const Create_element = () => {
        const data_name = window.prompt("Enter Data Name");;
        if (data_name ) {
          setData((data) =>
            data.map((el, i) =>
              i === active_menu
                ? {
                    ...el,
                    myData: [...el.myData, { data_name,  }]
                  }
                : el
            )
          );
        }
      };
```

To delete the tab:

```
    setData((data) => data.filter((_, i) => i !== index));

  const deleteData = (index) => {
    console.log("delete", index);
    setData((data) =>
      data.map((dataItem, dataIndex) =>
        dataIndex === active_menu
          ? {
              ...data[dataIndex],
              myData: data[dataIndex].myData.filter((_, i) => index !== i)
            }
          : dataItem
      )
    );
  };
```

**Edit / Update**

I just want to edit the name of tab as well as the name of my nested elements name.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-flower-61lxt?file=/src/App.js) I have added delete functionality, now just want to edit Tab name and elements name inside each tab

**Edit / Update**

How can I update the name of particular element inside the tabs

Answer (score 1):

create json like :

```
const tabJSON = {"home":"<element>","contact":"<element", ...}
```

assign that to state in hooks :

```
const [tab, setTab] = useState(tabJSON);
```

onClick pass key like:

```
onClick={()=>handleClick(key)}
```

in handleClick update tab

```
handleClick=param=>{
   const updatedTab = {...tab};
   if(param in tab){
     delete updatedTab[param]; //remove updated tab and its content
 }
    setTab(updatedTab); 
}
```

for update Tab:

```
const handlEditTab=(index,tabName)=>{
    const newTabName = prompt(`Rename ${tabName}`);
    /**
     * here any layover form can be used or any condition also can be put for tab name
     */
    if(tabName){
      const newTabs = [...data];
      const indexOfElement = newTabs.findIndex(obj=>obj.id===index);
      newTabs[indexOfElement].name= newTabName;
      setData(newTabs)
    }
  }
```

in JSX call this function like given:

```
...
<div onDoubleClick={()=>handlEditTab(li.id,li.name)} className="dashboard_name col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
...
```

[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-easley-ti69s?file=/src/App.js:3483-3653) is the working example.
here I used double click to update and single click to select, you can update it accordingly as per requirement.

Comment: I canot change the data, this is what I am getting from server end, i think I am missing something in my own code

Comment: assign response of the server to another variable and then you can edit it, consider ‘tab’ as response from server.

Comment: please check my edit, I have added dlete functionality, now I just want to add edit the name of tab and elements

Comment: hey, updated the answer, hopefully this will workout for you.

Comment: Hey here I can only edit tab name, how can I edit the elements names also which is inside the tabs

Comment: instead of window prompt, open layover with the pre filled fields of all element of selected tab, on submit update that.

Comment: I am asking about that element which are inside the tabs, how can I edit those names

Answer (score 0):

When you are mapping over items (or subitems) it is best practice to have a unique key for each item in the map. This key should not be the index in the array as this could change (i.e. on a delete). With a unique key React can manage the state properly and it will also help you edit the according item (or subitems).

I've added a `unique_id` property to your subitems (`myData`).

```
data1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Maxi",
    myData: [
      {
        unique_id: "61225_wsadfig",
        data_name: "div1",
        data_title: "div1 tittle"
      },
      ... etc.
]
```

I suggest using a unique id library like `uuid` to generate these values.

Then, whenever you add a new item you can set the `unique_id` with `uuid()`.

```
const Create_element = () => {
    const data_name = window.prompt("Enter Data Name");
    const data_title = window.prompt("Enter Data Title");

    if (data_name && data_title) {
      setData((data) =>
        data.map((el, i) =>
          i === active_menu
            ? {
                ...el,
                myData: [
                  ...el.myData,
                  { data_name, data_title, unique_id: uuidv4() }
                ]
              }
            : el
        )
      );
    }
  };
```

Finally, to edit the value of your element in question: pass a `editData` function as a prop like you do with your `deleteData` function.

I used an `<input/>` to record the new value of the users input. With an input make sure you set the `name` property of the input to this new `unique_id`. This will lead you to being able to match the `unique_id` with the input in question like so:

```
  const editData = (e, index) => {
    const dataName = e.currentTarget.name;
    const newValue = e.currentTarget.value;

    setData((data) =>
      data.map((dataItem, dataIndex) => {
        return {
          ...dataItem,
          myData: dataItem.myData.map((x, i) => {
            if (x.unique_id === dataName) {
              return {
                ...x,
                data_title: newValue
              };
            }
            return x;
          })
        };
      })
    );
  };
```

Here is a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-currying-o2fi2?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your elements pretty similar as you've done with your delete functionality but instead use `map` function

So in order to rename your tab you can map through your whole collection, and if item has matching index, update it's name, otherwise just return same item:

```
const renameTab = (index) => () => {
    const newName = window.prompt("Enter New Name");
    if (newName) {
      setData(data => data.map((dataItem, idx) => {
        if (index === idx) {
          return {
            ...dataItem,
            name: newName
          }
        }

        return d;
      }));
    }
}
```

Here is [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-sanne-l26hj) with ability to rename tab/element and remove tab/element - please note that "E" button is to initiate edit.